# The usage of the verb 'commit'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

The last sentence evades me. What does the clause, 'they've committed to~' 
mean?   I've referred to a number of dictionaries in vain.

> But these influxes of renewable energy were achieved during extremely
>   favourable conditions, and right now there's no way to store this
>   energy for later use, which makes it hard to completely cut out fossil
>   fuels. If Sweden has success in developing new energy storage
>   technology, as they've committed to in their new budget, they could
>   well lead the way. Let the race begin.
>
> > [Sweden Sets Its Sights on Becoming The World's First Fossil Fuel-Free Nation](https://www.sciencealert.com/sweden-sets-its-sights-on-becoming-the-world-s-first-fossil-fuel-free-nation)

Answer (score 1):

The sense of [*commit*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit) being used here is this one:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2 b** : to pledge or assign to some particular course or use
>   // *commit* all troops to the attack

In other words, they have agreed to the details of the new budget and (most likely) already moved the funds to the appropriate accounts under that plan.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Bassford. Another question... Is 'to'  a preposition? What is omitted after 'to'  ?

Comment: @Nofear *To* is being used as a preposition. The object of *committed* comes before it in this case. They are *committed to new energy storage technology*, but the sentence structure is inverted: *new energy storage technology, as they've committed to*.